# How to use cypher to create multiple edges for a graph in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image]

I want to create a data graph in neo4j with cypher like the one in this figure.

```
create (v1:D)-[]->(v2:C)
create (v1:D)-[]->(v3:A)
create (v1:D)-[]->(v4:B)
create (v2:C)-[]->(v1:D)
create (v2:C)-[]->(v3:A)
create (v3:A)-[]->(v1:D)
create (v3:A)-[]->(v2:C)
create (v4:B)-[]->(v1:D)
```

Is it possible to create such a graph in cypher rather than using csv import from neo4j? One thing we need is the identifiers for the created nodes.

update: the neo4j version is 5.3.0

Comment: The create statements you give, don't give the desired graph as shown in the picture. Also, what is your neo4j version.

Comment: added the neo4j version. I was wondering whether this is something cypher can support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `CREATE` command, that's why multiple nodes are getting created. Try using `MERGE`:

```
MERGE (a:A{id: randomUUID()})
MERGE (b:B{id: randomUUID()})
MERGE (c:C{id: randomUUID()})
MERGE (d:D{id: randomUUID()})
MERGE (a)-[r1:R{id: randomUUID()}]->(b)
MERGE (b)-[r2:R{id: randomUUID()}]->(c)
MERGE (a)-[r3:R{id: randomUUID()}]->(c)
MERGE (c)-[r4:R{id: randomUUID()}]->(d)
RETURN a,b,c,d, r1,r2,r3,r4
```